# What's the meaning of "It makes the landscape dangerous to navigate"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've come across the sentence below:

> Morning comes slowly. Overnight, the falling snow, so peaceful, has
>   turned to sleet, coating everything in brittle ice, **making the
>   landscape even more dangerous to navigate.**

What does the marked sentence mean?
There are some meanings for the word **navigate**.
Does it mean "to successfully find a way from one place to another" [1] here?

[1] https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/navigate

Comment: Many speakers do not associate the word with the sea nowadays. It is used of any situation where you have to find your "way", literally or figuratively: difficult romantic relationships, business meetings, cross-country car-trips, life in the demimonde, whatever.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. Navigate does have multiple meanings but in this context it refers to the act of crossing or traversing a difficult landscape.